# Auto increment numbers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have piece of code to make order numbers like `$order->order_no = 'TXT'.date('Ymd').'001';` this simply make results like: `TXT20190213001` my issue is how to make `001` part dynamic in order to increment it like `001` `002` `003` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Get the last order id
$lastorderId = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->order_no;

// Get last 3 digits of last order id
$lastIncreament = substr($lastorderId, -3);

// Make a new order id with appending last increment + 1
$newOrderId = 'TXT' . date('Ymd') . str_pad($lastIncreament + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

However, this will let you have max 999 numbers. You can have 001-999 fo everyday so you can have max 999 orders per day to no exceed 3 digit increments for a day.

To simplify :

You can use table's auto incremented primary key and add leading zeros to it.

```
$orderStmt = DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'orders'");
$nextPrimaryKeyId = $orderStmt[0]->Auto_increment;

Now you can add leading zeros : 

$nextPrimaryKeyId = str_pad($nextPrimaryKeyId, 6, 0);
// Above will make increment id 23 as 000023
```

and then use it inside new order.

or.. You can use a uuid [package](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) to accomplish  the same.

Comment: I'm getting `Property [order_no] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.` code: `$order = new Order;
        $lastorderId = Order::latest()->order_no;
        $lastIncreament = substr($lastorderId, -3);`

Comment: Updated my answer, you can do `orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()`

Comment: it says `Trying to get property 'order_no' of non-object` PS: i cleared my db so it's first order ever i think thats why

Comment: You can do `$lastorderId = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->order_no ?? 1;`

Comment: that was working but is it ok to use 0 instead of 1? ` ?? 1; ` now it starts from `002`

Comment: ohh sure,  you can use 0 :)